# Protocol SSL is not working with Curl

Tags: opensuse, git, curl, ssl, clone

I am trying to clone [Wayland](https://github.com/nobled/wayland) repository from git *(for a project)* but git clone command is throwing me an error.

I installed curl ([from here](https://github.com/curl/curl)). After cloning `make && make install`. *Earlier I had a different version which was working fine with git.*

Then I again tried cloning [Wayland](https://github.com/nobled/wayland) repository and this error popped.

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/nobled/wayland.git/': Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

so tried building curl as `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl` but I am not able to make any visible changes in curl's behaviour

> /usr/local/ssl is a bad --with-ssl prefix!

I also tried this with `/etc/ssl/` but failed

> /etc/ssl is a bad --with-ssl prefix!

Any suggestion what may have caused this?

Comment: Is reinstalling the former curl out of question? You appear to already known that it is the curl you compiled that is causing this, why the question at the end?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Inspite of the fact that this has something to do with the curl (newer version) that I installed. But even when I am doing `./configure --with-ssl=/path/to/some/ssl` it is not working. That leaves me wondering if I am giving the right SSL path. Which path should I use? What should be the content of the directory(of which the path is).

Comment: I can confirm the error with openssl v1.1.1a, at least I wasn't able to build curl with it. Try openssl 1.0.2q. For more details about the different versions check https://www.openssl.org/source/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch

```
--with-ssl={gnutls,openssl}
```

needs the location of the the header files (*.h) usually in `/usr/include/openssl` it's a good idea to run configure with `--includedir=/usr/include/` telling configure where to look for includes.

If `/usr/include/openssl` exists on your system and is having `*.h` files - it should be the right place.

You need to install the

`openssl-devel` (cent / redhat with yum) or `libssl-dev` (debian, ubuntu with apt) package otherwise.  (Or clone the files from github.com 1.1.1 stable branch).

`--with-ssl=/usr/include/openssl`

**EDIT**:

```
ls /usr/include/openssl
aes.h        buffer.h     cterr.h   engineerr.h  md5.h          pem.h        rsa.h        symhacks.h
asn1err.h    camellia.h   ct.h      engine.h     mdc2.h         pkcs12err.h  safestack.h  tls1.h
asn1.h       cast.h       des.h     e_os2.h      modes.h        pkcs12.h     seed.h       tserr.h
asn1_mac.h   cmac.h       dherr.h   err.h        objectserr.h   pkcs7err.h   sha.h        ts.h
asn1t.h      cmserr.h     dh.h      evperr.h     objects.h      pkcs7.h      srp.h        txt_db.h
asyncerr.h   cms.h        dsaerr.h  evp.h        obj_mac.h      rand_drbg.h  srtp.h       uierr.h
async.h      comperr.h    dsa.h     hmac.h       ocsperr.h      randerr.h    ssl2.h       ui.h
bioerr.h     comp.h       dtls1.h   idea.h       ocsp.h         rand.h       ssl3.h       whrlpool.h
bio.h        conf_api.h   ebcdic.h  kdferr.h     opensslconf.h  rc2.h        sslerr.h     x509err.h
blowfish.h   conferr.h    ecdh.h    kdf.h        opensslv.h     rc4.h        ssl.h        x509.h
bnerr.h      conf.h       ecdsa.h   lhash.h      ossl_typ.h     rc5.h        stack.h      x509v3err.h
bn.h         cryptoerr.h  ecerr.h   md2.h        pem2.h         ripemd.h     storeerr.h   x509v3.h
buffererr.h  crypto.h     ec.h      md4.h        pemerr.h       rsaerr.h     store.h      x509_vfy.h
```

**EDIT2**:

Make sure it's openssl v1.0.2. Compiling curl doesn't seem to work with openssl v1.1.1a

Comment: Yea I tried this just now. giving the error as `configure: error: /usr/local/include/openssl is a bad --with-ssl prefix!`. I am not sure about the root cause.

Comment: why `/usr/local/include` and not `/usr/include/` ?

Comment: that's my default for manual installations. Should that cause a problem here?

Comment: If /usr/include/openssl exists on your system and is having *.h files - it should be the right place.

Comment: Well I have the *.h files in /usr/local/include/openssl Why should this not work? Is it necessary to put in /usr/include ? *(Can we go to chat? I don't know how to launch it)*

Comment: Reinstalled using `--with-ssl=/etc/ssl/certs` again. It did the trick this time (NO Idea why). while running the curl command added `--cacert [file]`. Solved.